# How do I make hand bend up and down Horizontally?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

As you can see in the image below the forearm is able to twist ok on the Y axis, but the hand can't turn up or down as it also bends on the Y axis. Is there a way to fix this without using shape keys or drivers? Because i don't know python code.
[image]

I got rid of limit rot and damped track but now the wrist has this weird twist because the 3 bones in the forearm seem to reset back to their origial position. How do I fix that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume a bone constraint is added to the hand bone, which limits it. You can upload your blend file so we can take a better look at it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BOrPoSmM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BOrPoSmM/)

Answer (score 0):

Your hand bone has 2 constraints: *Damped Track* and *Limit Rotation*, so it can't rotate freely, the *Damped Track* constraint makes it point towards the bone called *Hand con.L* and the *Limit Rotation* limits its rotation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By disabling both of your constraints (eye icons) you can get full control over the hand. You can even just disable one of them and see if it makes you the desired change.

You can also play with the values of the constraints if you want to keep some limitations to the bone.

[image]